# Backup and restore cdc tables

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, cdc

Currently working on customer releases for our product. First step is to compare the customer database with our current dev db. Apparently we need to shut off cdc to do this, which drops all of the system cdc tables. Is there any way to backup and restore these tables for after we've finished comparing the two db's?

Comment: "Apparently we need to shut off cdc to do this" That shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I had a similar thought, but a senior dev is claiming we do need to...

Comment: CDC explicitly has affordance for two capture instances on a table to allow for a transition to a new table definition/different columns to capture. Agreeing with @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - I'd dig into the claim that CDC needs to be disabled at all; "senior dev" is not synonymous with "infallible".

Answer (score 0):

> Apparently we need to shut off cdc to do this.

Completely agree with @DavidBrown that it isn't necessary to disable CDC for comparing the databases.

CDC enabled database simply means that your database captures the data change automatically. It manages that changed data in a separate table therefore you can still compare your database with different database without disabling CDC.

In case if required, you can restore the CDC enabled database by referring this third-party tutorial.

[Restoring a SQL Server database that uses Change Data Capture](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2421/restoring-a-sql-server-database-that-uses-change-data-capture/)